# I placed icons created with the "Flutter custom icons generator". But something is wrong.I would like to set up icons with a SVG-like design

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-design

## issue

I want to put icons like SVG.
But I can't put it.

- The dart file generated by the Flutter custom icons generator.

```
class WDLogo {
  WDLogo._();

  static const _kFontFam = 'WDLogo';
  static const String? _kFontPkg = null;

  static const IconData arrow_back = IconData(0xe801, fontFamily: _kFontFam, fontPackage: _kFontPkg);
  static const IconData arrow_forward = IconData(0xe802, fontFamily: _kFontFam, fontPackage: _kFontPkg);
  static const IconData menu = IconData(0xe803, fontFamily: _kFontFam, fontPackage: _kFontPkg);
}
```

- pubspec.yaml

```
  fonts:
    - family: WDLogo
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/WDLogo.ttf
```

- icon widget

```
 "Icon(WDLogo.arrow_back))"
```

https://www.fluttericon.com/

- SVG (Correct icon)
  [image]
- Mac folder

[image]

- Flutter custom icons generator

[image]

- Mac font preview

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your fonts to asset folder and defined it on pubspec.yaml file like this

```
flutter: 
   fonts:
   - family:  MyFlutterApp
      fonts:
       - asset: fonts/MyFlutterApp.ttf
```

first add plugin ,link : https://pub.dev/packages/fluttericon/install
to your pubsepec.yaml file. after that import file.
then
Call Your icons like this

```
final myIcons = const <Widget>[
    const Icon(Typicons.attention),
    const Icon(Fontelico.emo_wink),
    const Icon(Linecons.globe),
];
```

DONT USE LIKE THIS `"Icon(WDLogo.arrow_back))"`,

if You need to use SVG , you can use this Flutter svg plugin for that ,
link for plugin https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg

```
final String assetName = 'assets/image.svg';
final Widget svg = SvgPicture.asset(
  assetName,
  semanticsLabel: 'Acme Logo'
);
```

Comment: - family: WDLogo
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/WDLogo.ttf

Comment: It is my fonts :

Comment: Currently, the icon is called "Icon(WDLogo.arrow_back))" like this.

Comment: check now i edited my answer

Comment: You mean not use .ttf ?